# Login with rvest/httr

Tags: r, httr

I am trying manage logging in with httr.

I have tried the following:

```
username<-"email"; password<-"password"
page<-html_session("https://www.crowdcube.com/login")
page<-request_POST(page,url=page$response$url,
                       body=list("email"=username,
                                 "password"=password
                                 ,"redirect_url"="https://www.crowdcube.com"),
                     encode='json',verbose()
                       )
```

and simply this (I have tried to provide a url to redirect to, but that did not work either):

```
x <- POST("https://www.crowdcube.com/login", authenticate(username, password),config(followlocation = 0), encode="json", verbose())
```

He is what the latter produced (the first one also triggers 302 error):

```
-> POST /login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.crowdcube.com
-> Authorization: Basic iYmlAbWFpbC5ydToxUnVzc2
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.0 httr/1.4.1
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Cookie: CROWDCUBE=g59tvlaq5v5lrpsgogak9; __cfduid=d18fd4953c89e16e5713cff6ba34262
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 0
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<- Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 23:59:49 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
<- Cache-control: no-store, no-cache
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Location: /login
<- X-Request-Id: 3bf2-5d1b-483d-9f81-a78af46a
<- x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
<- CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
<- cf-request-id: 4600000015f00a81e00000
<- Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- Server: cloudflare
<- CF-RAY: 31cc99215f0-ARN
```

Rseleniumcan probably manage the problem, but I am trying to avoid it

Edit in response to @MrFlick. The first version produces the following:

```
-> POST /login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.crowdcube.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.0 httr/1.4.1
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Cookie: AWSALBCORS=fLpF/isCxxMpnt/e2/lc1CGgyln7VFK6uuHNe94mwJKERlhwo8tgXwd0rDlEwZOGdKr6RzYFAvHhk82tgefXSBVqRE7q4le+1H02+QS+a0/eyMlT6vKMBIkpDi5k; CROWDCUBE=rc279ndia8vjstjb95g0l2pvt1; AWSALB=fLpF/isCxxMpnt/e2/lc1CGgyln7VFK6uuHNe94mwJKERlhwo8tgXwd0rDlEwZOGdKr6RzYFAvHhk82tgefXSBVqRE7q4le+1H02+QS+a0/eyMlT6vKMBIkpDi5k; __cfduid=d81f8fe2764634872724f3ea67e9226581605830327
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Content-Length: 92
-> 
>> {"email":"eeeee","password":"ppppp","redirect_url":"https://www.crowdcube.com"}

<- HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<- Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2020 00:44:39 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
<- Cache-control: no-store, no-cache
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Location: /login
<- X-Request-Id: 5eaeee34-f6e1-474c-96bf-f9185226fc78
<- x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
<- CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
<- cf-request-id: 0684b5538d00001c06f2970000000001
<- Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- Server: cloudflare
<- CF-RAY: 5f4e24cc1f471c06-OSL
<- 
-> GET /login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.crowdcube.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.0 httr/1.4.1
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Referer: https://www.crowdcube.com/login
-> Cookie: AWSALBCORS=fLpF/isCxxMpnt/e2/lc1CGgyln7VFK6uuHNe94mwJKERlhwo8tgXwd0rDlEwZOGdKr6RzYFAvHhk82tgefXSBVqRE7q4le+1H02+QS+a0/eyMlT6vKMBIkpDi5k; CROWDCUBE=rc279ndia8vjstjb95g0l2pvt1; AWSALB=fLpF/isCxxMpnt/e2/lc1CGgyln7VFK6uuHNe94mwJKERlhwo8tgXwd0rDlEwZOGdKr6RzYFAvHhk82tgefXSBVqRE7q4le+1H02+QS+a0/eyMlT6vKMBIkpDi5k; __cfduid=d81f8fe2764634872724f3ea67e9226581605830327
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2020 00:44:39 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
<- Cache-control: no-store, no-cache
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- X-Request-Id: fda74a48-75a0-4420-98b5-d565b1dc8df8
<- x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
<- CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
<- cf-request-id: 0684b5542300001c06f7b5d000000001
<- Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- Server: cloudflare
<- CF-RAY: 5f4e24cd08101c06-OSL
<- Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: The `authenticate()` function would only work if the site used basic HTTP authentication which is unlikely. What's the error you get from the rvest version? If you need to support a login mechanism that requires tracking state/cookies/javascript, you'll need to use `Rselenium`. Or you'll need to do the work of reverse engineering the login flow for that particular website and rebuild it in R.

Comment: @MrFlick. I have updated my question with the output from the rvest version. I am still keeping my fingers crossed. How does one reverse engineer?

Comment: So what exactly is not working with that version? You seem to be getting a successful status code (200).

Comment: As you see it gives an error of expected redirection (as far as I understand 302). De facto, it stays on login page and nothing happens. If I jump_to another page. I see that I am still logged out.

Comment: Hi @BBB, did you ever figure out the problem? I have a similar issue where I get 200 status code but when I jump to another page I'm still logged out